# How can i get list of integer from rx.Observable asynchronously?

Tags: rx-java

I want the list of integer but my function is returning rx.Subscription. So how can I get list asynchronously? I am already aware of toBlocking() method. So please provide me the solution other than that.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Can you provide the sample of your code?

Comment: ob.map(// something).toList().toBlocking().single()
where ob is wrapped inside the observable.
just want to convert above code into asynchronous one.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

if the function you are using return an observable you can subscribe on it this way and you will receive the value asynchronously(assuming the observable is delivering them asynchronously):

```
const obs = yourFunction()
obs.subscribe(value => {
    // do whatever you want with the value here
    // console.log(value)
})
```

Comment: actually, I am using rx library in my java program and doing like above, giving me error like the returning unexpected result
a.subscribe(data -> {
                System.out.println("dhdjdj");
                return data;});

Comment: @TheMx it's not `Java`